# CoffeeScript - remove an item once pushed

Tags: coffeescript

How can I remove an element from the array which was pushed in with `push`?

```
animals = []

class Cat

cat = new Cat

animals.push cat
```

now can I say something like

```
animals.pull cat
```

to take the cat away from the array? Presuming that the `cat` variable is the same one that was pushed inside. I am just trying to create a kind of a dynamic collection..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `push` an element to an array, it's added at the last position. You can then `pop` it back. These two methods are useful if you want to model a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) with an array.

```
array = []

array.push 'hello' # array is now ['hello']
array.push 'world' # array is now ['hello', 'world']

alert array.pop() # alerts 'world', array is now ['hello']
alert array.pop() # alerts 'hello', array is now []
```

Answer (score 5):

```
index = animals.indexOf cat
animals.splice index, 1 if index isnt -1
```

Remember, a CoffeeScript array is just a JavaScript array, so you can look at [any appropriate documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
animals = []

class Cat

cat = new Cat

animals.push cat

anotherReferenceToCat = animals.pop()

# animals.length === 0
```